# PDO prepared statements converting single quotes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I couldn't find clear answer for this simple(?) question.

I recently moved to PDO and I made simple insert-query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO item(name) values (:name)";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->bindParam(':name', $name);
```

Now, when I throw parameter "Dina's", it's apparently converted to

```
"Dina&#39;s"
```

(or atleast this is what it seems in phpmyadmin).

Can I prevent this conversion somehow, so that data is stored as it was supplied on bindParam? Or is this current converted value the best way to have data stored?

Comment: This code converts nothing, you should check where `$name` comes from and what value it really has.

Comment: Oh darn, you are right! I didn't notice `$name` conversion due to long stack. Thanks for pointing my error. I really thought there was some strange conversion setting messing storing procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code converts nothing, you should check where $name comes from and what value it really has.